# Not able to install spring context dependency in Maven project

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm very new to Spring. I just tried exploring it and added Spring Context dependency in pom.xml but it's showing error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbjiF.png) What might be the reason?

Comment: Do a maven reimport in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to reinstall your artifact from scratch via mvn -U clean install?

Comment: 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Do I need to add maven to environment variable, if yes, then how? I just downloaded IntelliJ and JDK11 and added IntelliJ to my path variable? What additional configuration, I've to do for Maven. As Maven comes preinstalled with IntelliJ.

Comment: You either can run custom maven command directly in IntelliJ - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html or sort out where it has been installed by IntelliJ installation procedure, and add it into your environment variables. And then run the command.